# Codeigniter: getting the value of textbox on $row

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just want to ask how can you get the value of the texbox in this code:

Here is my view:

```
    <div class="row">
    <h3><input type='text' name="table1" value='<?php echo $table1; ?>' style='border: none; background-color: transparent;' readonly/></h3>
    <div class="table_design">
        <button style='position: absolute; top:290px; right: 173px;' class='btn_addinventory btn-success btn-sm' id='btn_addinventory' name='btn_addinventory'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>&nbsp;Add Inventory</button>
        <table class="boom_table">           
            <tr>
                <?php foreach($sample1 as $field) { ?>
                <th><?php echo $field->name; ?></th>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr> 
            <?php foreach($select1 as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->ID; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
        <?php foreach($sample1 as $field) { ?>
        <input type="text" name="txt_rowname" value="<?php echo $field->name; ?>"/>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
public function inventory_new(){
        $tablenaming1 = $_POST['ninja7'];
//        var_dump($tablenaming1);
//        exit;
        $this->session->userdata('login_session');
        $this->data['title'] = "Inventory";
        $this->load->vars($this->data);


        $this->load->view('homeview');

        $select_inv['inventorytype'] = $this->inventory_model->select_tables();
        $this->load->view('inventoryview', $select_inv);


        $sample['sample'] = $this->inventory_model->select_fields_2($_POST['ninja7']);
        $select_details['select'] = $this->inventory_model->select_queries2($this->input->post());
//        var_dump($select_details);
//        exit;
        $value_array = array('sample1' => $sample['sample'],
                             'table1' => $tablenaming1,
                             'select1' => $select_details['select']);

        $this->load->view('sampleviewtable', $value_array);

        $this->load->view('footer_view');

    }
```

And here is my model:

```
public function select_fields_2($tablename2){
     $fields = $this->db->field_data($tablename2);
     return $fields;
 }

public function select_queries2($tablename){
     $select_table = $this->db->select('*')
                              ->from($tablename['ninja7']);
     return $select_table->get()->result();
 }
```

In my view above you will see:

```
                <?php foreach($select1 as $row) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->ID; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
```

And this:

```
        <?php foreach($sample1 as $field) { ?>
        <input type="text" name="txt_rowname" value="<?php echo $field->name; ?>"/>
        <?php } ?>
```

I want to get the value of the `<input type="text" name="txt_rowname" value="<?php echo $field->name; ?>"/>` from my view, For example: if the value of this textbox is equal to 'Name' instead of `$row->ID` now it should be `$row->Name`. I really can't figure out this yet, I want to pass the value of the textbox instead of putting 'ID' on $row. Is there a way to do that?

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Comment: PHP cannot read your HTML input field's value on the same request. Can you please clarify your question a little?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: On my code above, in '$row->ID' I want to replace ID to the value of the textbox. For example: If the value of the textbox is equal to 'Name' Instead of $row->ID, it should be $row->Name. So is it possible?

Comment: Sorry please explains it clearly if you want help from anyone here as your question doesn't seems to be understandable.

Also what data you have in your $sample1 and $select1 ?

Give us more details in order to help you.

Comment: @Zeeshan Ok, let me edit the question, but I think the data in $sample1 and $select1 is not important because I just want to get the value of the textbox.

Comment: @Zeeshan I've edited my question, I hope you can understand it now. I had a hard time explaining 'coz it's confusing for me too. Lol.

Comment: @eljon_i3 ok but from where you want to get that textbox value that is where you want to assign or use that textbox value ?

Comment: @Zeeshan I didn't quite get your question. I want to assign the textbox value to $row. Instead of $row->ID, it would be $row->'value of the texbox'. I want to assign the value of the textbox to be a replacement for ID.

Comment: sorry but you have made it very confusing and i am unable to get what you want to achieve and why you want to assign textbox value in rowID and if you don't want to use rowID then why you are taking it.

Again i am asking you as clear you will be the help you will get is better.

Comment: Are you asking about submitting the form ? There are 2 text boxes in your code. Which one you want to access?

Please be clear with the question

Comment: @Zeeshan I am loading datas from a table in the database. I am loading different table with different columns. the echo $field->name; in my textbox corresponds to the columns of a certain table. Just COLUMNS. while $row->ID corresponds to the datas inside the column ID of a table. My point is what if a table selected doesn't have a column ID? What if there are set of different columns. That's why I need to get the value of $field->name; that's in my textbox.

Comment: @Zeeshan I want $row to be dynamic.

Comment: @MRSrinivas I want to access the textbox named "txt_rowname". I've put it in the question.

Comment: Really you are making things hard for yourself.What i got from your question so far is you have list of tables in database and you want to output its table structure when clicked or something like that.

Confirm this if you are trying to achieve this

Comment: Where do you want access `txt_rowname` model/controller ? What should be the possible value ?

Comment: @Zeeshan Yes that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @eljon_i3 Please check my answer and feel free to ask if you have further doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eljon as per your comments and what i understand your requirement is you need to populate table structure on clicking table name.

So,in codeigniter their is a simple way to achieve this like this:

```
$fields = $this->db->list_fields('table_name');

foreach ($fields as $field)
{
   echo $field;
}
```

Here 'list_fields' will give you your fields name of specified table.

If you want to get field data you can try this out :

```
$fields = $this->db->field_data('table_name');

foreach ($fields as $field)
{
   echo $field->name;
   echo $field->type;
   echo $field->max_length;
   echo $field->primary_key;
}
```

Here is more information in codeigniter documentation
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/fields.html

Hope this helps you.

Regards,
Zeeshan.

----- Update ------
You can populate database table in tabular structure using inbuilt codeigniter library,you can directly echo that table in your view the code goes like this:

```
$this->load->library('table');

$query = $this->db->get('table_name');

$page_data['db_table'] = $this->table->generate($query);
```

In your view :

```
echo $db_table
```

--- Update 2 ----
Update as per your comments and requirements

you can use set_template of table class to set the id as

```
$tmpl = array ( 'table_open' => '<table id="YOUR_ID" class="mytable">' );
$this->table->set_template($tmpl);
```

More details regarding table class here https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html

Comment: I already have that code. What I want to access is the data's on that fields. That fields corresponds to the column names right? I want to access the data's inside of those column names.

Comment: You want to browse the table or want structure of table ?

Comment: The code that you answered is the structure. I want to browse the table.

Comment: check my updated answer..hope it will help you this time

Comment: Do I still have to use 'return $query->result();'?

Comment: i guess its not required.just give it a try the code i posted and it will work for you ?

Comment: It worked. But there is some errors though, I'm trying to load it in a <table> tag.

Comment: When I put echo $db_table inside the <td></td> tag it's creating a new table. so now I removed the <table> tag and just echoed $db_table. The problem now is I can't create an ID on that table because now it's like the <table> is auto-generated. I need to have an ID to that table because I will use that table on other views.

Comment: Ok.So you can use set_template of table class to set the id as 
` down vote accepted
 

Have you tried this before generating table ?

`$tmpl = array ( 'table_open'  => 
'<table id="YOUR_ID" class="mytable">' );

    $this->table->set_template($tmpl);`

Comment: Yep it worked. Thank you. Is it okay to add other html codes on table_open? Like I want to add this before generating a table `$query2 = $this->db->get('tablename');
return $query2->result();
foreach ($query2 as $row){
   echo $row->ID;
} ` Is it okay if I add that code?

Comment: Check this out for details regarding table class 
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/table.html

Also i updated my answer if it helped you accept it as answer.